# Is there a svn or git solution that enables live preview

Tags: svn, apache, repository, git-svn, live-preview

I would like to know if there is a solution (open source project or webservice) available that offers a svn or git repository together with an apache server and database. I am searching for such a solution because I would like to get the benefits of developing with a subversion system. On the other side I need a preview of the final result to see what the code looks like on different browsers.

Hope anybody can help me!
regards,
Markus

Answer (score 1):

You could place your Git repository in the docroot of your Apache. Then you can edit files, commit them and hav at all times a live preview at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at git-instaweb.  It starts a web server in your git repo, so you can browse the files, and it includes gitweb.cgi so you can quickly get data about your repo.